# Variance of $n$-dimensional Brownian motion (Oksendal)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I apologize if this is a trivial question but I am confused by eq. $2.2.9$ in Oksendal (see image below).  If $B_t$ is $n$-dimensional Brownian motion then isn't $B_t\sim\mathcal N(\mathbf x,tI_n)$ a $n$ vector? If so, what is meant by $E^x[(B_t-x)^2]$? Is it interpreted as the determinant of the covariance matrix (this would give the same solution of $nt$)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is to be understood in the sense of a scalar product, $\newcommand{\IE}{\mathbb{E}}$
$$
\IE^x[(B_t-x)^2]=\IE^x[\|B_t-x\|^2]=\sum_{k=1}^n\IE^x[(B_{k,t}-x_k)^2]=nt.
$$
Or you could also call it the sum over the main diagonal of the covariance matrix.

Comment: Since $x\in\Bbb R^n$ do we need the $\mathbf 1_n$?  From what I understand you saying we could also write $\mathsf E^x[(B_t-x)^2]=\mathsf E^x[(B_t-x)^\mathsf T(B_t-x)]=\cdots=nt$ (assuming vectors are columns).

Comment: No, you are right. I was irritated by the large vector $(x,x,x,..,x)$ of $k$ copies of the vector $x$.

Comment: I agree that the notation is confusing.  Thank you.